# Check if file exist, if so add number

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written a code that saves emails as pdf in Folder1 and downloads the attachments in Folder2. Now the problem I have is that if an attachment has the same name it overwrites it.

I tried to add this piece of code so it automatically adds a number in front of the attachments name but it didn't work.

```
Dim x As Integer
x = 0
If strFile <> strFile Then
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
    objAttachments.Item(i) = Replace(objAttachments.Item(i), " ", "_")

Else
    strFile = strFile
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile x & strFile  
    objAttachments.Item(i) = Replace(objAttachments.Item(i), " ", "_")

    x = x + 1

End If
```

Here is the whole code:

```
' Get the path to your My Documents folder
strFolderpath = "C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\bestanden\"
On Error Resume Next

' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = "C:\Users\Kevin\Downloads\bestanden\"

' Check each selected item for attachments. If attachments exist,
' save them to the strFolderPath folder and strip them from the item.
For Each objMsg In objSelection

    ' This code only strips attachments from mail items.
    ' If objMsg.class=olMail Then
    ' Get the Attachments collection of the item.
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFiles = ""

    If lngCount > 0 Then
        ' We need to use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.
        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
            ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
            ' Get the file name.
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).Filename
            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
            strFile = Replace(strFile, " ", "_")

            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            If strFile <> strFile Then
               objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
               objAttachments.Item(i) = Replace(objAttachments.Item(i), " ", "_")
            Else
               strFile = strFile
               objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile & x
               objAttachments.Item(i) = Replace(objAttachments.Item(i), " ", "_")

                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: can this `If strFile <> strFile Then` ever be true?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Because if there isn't any file in the map it doesn't download an attachment. What should it be?

Comment: That's like saying `if 2 is not 2 then`  the same name variable will always equal itself.  Can you post the whole code, including the even triggering it.

Comment: If there is already a file with the same name it kinda works, but the for example if I have a word document already in Folder2 named 'building.docx' then it downloads the file named "building.docx1".

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, I have edited the post. You can see the whole code now.

Comment: @0m3r I've replied

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this

a function

```
Function FILE_EXISTS(strFolderPath As String, strFileName As String) As Boolean

With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    FILE_EXISTS = .fileexists(strFolderPath & "\" & strFileName)
End With

End Function
```

then

```
strFile="CheckFile.docx"
checkfileexists:
if FILE_EXISTS("c:\",strFile) then
      '    Add a number to strFile
      goto checkfileexists
else
      '   Save
end if
```

You can also add an upper limit number, say 100 to stop possibility of infinite counting in errors maybe

Comment: Nope.  You need to add this in a module, create a new module and add it in there.

Comment: where you have these checks `If strFile <> strFile Then` replace that with mine, so `if fileexists......add a number then recheck....else...save it...`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav This function is screaming Nathan. Why capital letters?

Comment: To try and emphasise the function use in the example above.

Comment: checkfileexists:
If FILE_EXISTS("c:\", strFile) Then
      objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile & x
      objAttachments.Item(i) = Replace(objAttachments.Item(i), " ", "_")
      GoTo checkfileexists
Else
      objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
      objAttachments.Item(i) = Replace(objAttachments.Item(i), " ", "_")
End If

Comment: Not quite, you need the goto after you've added the x, so if you have "file" then "file1", if x=1 then "file1" would be found.

Comment: I get an error at " If FILE_EXISTS("c:\", strFile)" -> "strFile" byref argument type mismatch

Comment: Could you add me on Discord? ivanosalima#4117

Answer (score 0):

Pure VBA without external libs & objects:

```
? LenB(Dir("YourFullPathName.Ext", vbNormal)) > 0
```

.

Comment: May I ask why `LenB()` and not just `Len()`?

Comment: @KostasK. It's easy. In this case we are not intersesting in real `Len()` of string in symbols, but want to detect that string is or not is 0(zero)-length in bytes only. `LenB()` is more faster than `Len()` in times (not sure :). Please, look on ... unfortunally I can't find the bookmark on the beautiful resourse :(

Comment: Why do I need this?

Comment: @MiranoDesigns Cause that the 1-st you asked in header is: 'Check if file exist ...'. It solved by 1(one, not tens by you I wan't even read) line. The 2-nd part is: '.., if so add number'. It is a separate task very related of notation you decide to arrange.

Answer (score 0):

*Try his function*

```
Private Function Unique(FldrPath As String) As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim FileUnique As String
        FileUnique = FldrPath
    Dim Ext As String
        Ext = "." & FSO.GetExtensionName(FldrPath)

    Dim x As Long
        x = 2
    Do While FSO.FileExists(FileUnique)
        FileUnique = Left(FldrPath, Len(FldrPath) - Len(Ext)) & "(" & x & ")" & Ext
        x = x + 1
    Loop

    Unique = FileUnique
End Function
```

*On your code simply change the following*

> ```
> strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
> ```

*To this*

> ```
> strFile = Unique(strFolderpath & strFile)
> ```

***MSDN: [FileExists Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t(v=vs.84).aspx) & [GetExtensionName Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/getextensionname-method)***

Comment: this didn't really changed anything. Maybe I did something wrong, this is what I did: I placed the function at the top of the code at first (didn't change anything to it). Then I changed the "strFile = strFolderpath & strFile" to yours "strFile = Unique(strFolderpath & strFile)"

Comment: If strFile <> strFile Then
               objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
               objAttachments.Item(i) = Replace(objAttachments.Item(i), " ", "_")
            Else
               strFile = strFile
               objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile & x
               objAttachments.Item(i) = Replace(objAttachments.Item(i), " ", "_")

                x = x + 1

Comment: Could you add me on Discord? ivanosalima#4117

Comment: @MiranoDesigns which office are you using?

Comment: the 2016 version.